# How to nest and loop step function in R, then output into separate Excel sheets

Tags: r, loops, nested, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to loop the `step` function in `R` through several Excel sheets of countries (AUD, EUR and SGD). I have merged the sheets into a single dataframe and I am trying to use `nest` and then `step` to do stepwise regression for each country. However, I am unable to integrate the loop into the `step` function.
After looping the `step` function, I would like to output the `coefficients` data (including t-stats, p-value etc.) into separate Excel sheets labelled by each country.
Would someone be able to help? I have included my attempt at looping, the `step` code without loop, and the data in `dput`.

```
### Loop with error
dfraw %>% group_by(dfraw, 'Country') %>%
          nest() %>%
          mutate(both_model = map(data, ~lm(VarY ~ ., data = dfraw))) %>%
          step(both_model, direction = "both") %>%
          group_by(Country) %>%
          summary(both_model)
```

```
### Functional Step code
both_model <- lm(VarY ~ ., data = dfSGD)
both_model <- step(both_model, direction = "both")
summary(both_model)
Out <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(Out, "SGD")
writeData(Out, sheet = "SGD", x = both_model$coefficients)
saveWorkbook(Out, "output.xlsx")
```

```
### dput(dfraw)
structure(list(Country = c("AUD", "AUD", "AUD", "AUD", "AUD", 
"AUD", "AUD", "AUD", "AUD", "AUD", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", 
"EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", 
"SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD", "SGD"), VarY = c(-0.0244845360824741, 
-0.0624174372523117, 0.0452624163437831, 0.0530749789385003, 
0.00624000000000002, -0.0295754491970107, 0.0327707684745209, 
-0.0182452800253847, 0.025048480930834, 0.0425666088601608, 0.0141000829416644, 
0.00154489276626668, 0.0621540695036749, 0.00905518537502115, 
-0.0209109380291228, 0.0147859922178988, -0.0318677573278799, 
-0.0293082203837354, -0.024208903799075, -0.0178405500836277, 
-0.0188187608569775, -0.0269326121253097, 0.0527939257325898, 
0.0383738835848475, -0.0163586791881248, 0.000606244316459614, 
-0.0250029554320841, -0.0177659080352996, -0.00352907144923342, 
0.0195835545331209), VarX1 = c(-0.000207994636117426, -0.14021214097687, 
0.019987000188707, 0.0905973411305785, 0.0606271485403591, 0.0460107119360711, 
0.0197995343444735, -0.0253560472301735, 0.045979341688096, 0.0432113473174549, 
-0.000207994636117426, -0.14021214097687, 0.019987000188707, 
0.0905973411305785, 0.0606271485403591, 0.0460107119360711, 0.0197995343444735, 
-0.0253560472301735, 0.045979341688096, 0.0432113473174549, -0.000207994636117426, 
-0.14021214097687, 0.019987000188707, 0.0905973411305785, 0.0606271485403591, 
0.0460107119360711, 0.0197995343444735, -0.0253560472301735, 
0.045979341688096, 0.0432113473174549), VarX2 = c(-0.04, 0.390000000000001, 
-1.015, -0.149999999999999, 0.234999999999999, 0.0650000000000004, 
0.0750000000000002, 0.22, -0.0449999999999999, 0.115, -0.115, 
-0.241, -0.252, -0.102, -0.0249999999999999, -0.0840000000000001, 
-0.47202, 0.28388, -0.21801, -0.2159, 0.43, 1.02, -0.919999999999999, 
-0.65, 0.0700000000000003, -0.63, -0.02, 0, -0.44, -0.29), VarX3 = c(0.0199999999999996, 
-0.734999999999999, 0.229, 0.220000000000001, 0.0739999999999998, 
-0.0760000000000005, 0.00800000000000001, 0.151, -0.04, -0.0739999999999998, 
0.146, -0.117999999999999, -0.234, -0.024, 0.266, 0.101999999999999, 
0.31286, 0.25693, -0.0321999999999996, 0.236699999999999, -0.0819999999999999, 
-0.778, -0.116, 1.075, -0.151, 0.073999999999999, 0.133000000000001, 
0.545999999999999, 0.175000000000001, 0.346), VarX4 = c(-0.0602317110633257, 
-0.0633604956143422, 0.0775846309806723, -0.0297417548946277, 
-0.0720518811692337, -0.0339499828708462, -0.00436185680343282, 
-0.0348429263427839, 0.0958382153499828, 0.0404280217883632, 
-0.0602317110633257, -0.0633604956143422, 0.0775846309806723, 
-0.0297417548946277, -0.0720518811692337, -0.0339499828708462, 
-0.00436185680343282, -0.0348429263427839, 0.0958382153499828, 
0.0404280217883632, -0.0602317110633257, -0.0633604956143422, 
0.0775846309806723, -0.0297417548946277, -0.0720518811692337, 
-0.0339499828708462, -0.00436185680343282, -0.0348429263427839, 
0.0958382153499828, 0.0404280217883632)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as you are wrapping the `lm()` in a `map()` call, you need to wrap
the `step()` part in `map()` too. Since `step()` expects the data used in `lm()` we need to make sure that we also pass the original data to each `step()` call. We can use `map2()` to pass the `lm` object *and* the data to the `step()` calls. Here is what that can look like:

```r
library(tidyverse)

res <- 
  dfraw |> 
  # If you want to run one model for each country you only need to
  # `group_by()` `Country`.
  group_by(Country) |>
  nest() |>
  mutate(both_model = map(data, ~ lm(VarY ~ ., data = .x)),
         step_model = map2(data, both_model, ~step(.y, direction = "both", trace = 0)))
```

`summary()` is not that useful for programmatically evaluating model results.
You can use `broom::glance()` and `broom::tidy()` instead:

```r
library(broom)

eval_res <- 
  res |> 
  mutate(quality = map(step_model, glance),
         estimates = map(step_model, tidy)) 

eval_res |> 
  select(Country, quality) |> 
  unnest(quality)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 13
#> # Groups:   Country [3]
#>   Country r.squared adj.r.squared  sigma statistic p.value    df logLik   AIC
#>   <chr>       <dbl>         <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 AUD         0.728         0.650 0.0230      9.35 0.0106      2   25.3 -42.6
#> 2 EUR         0.551         0.495 0.0206      9.81 0.0140      1   25.8 -45.5
#> 3 SGD         0.628         0.582 0.0180     13.5  0.00625     1   27.1 -48.2
#> # ℹ 4 more variables: BIC <dbl>, deviance <dbl>, df.residual <int>, nobs <int>

eval_res |> 
  select(Country, estimates) |> 
  unnest(estimates)
#> # A tibble: 7 × 6
#> # Groups:   Country [3]
#>   Country term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
#>   <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 AUD     (Intercept)  0.00355   0.00773     0.459 0.660  
#> 2 AUD     VarX1        0.370     0.126       2.93  0.0219 
#> 3 AUD     VarX4        0.291     0.134       2.17  0.0670 
#> 4 EUR     (Intercept)  0.00831   0.00732     1.14  0.289  
#> 5 EUR     VarX3       -0.116     0.0370     -3.13  0.0140 
#> 6 SGD     (Intercept) -0.00519   0.00587    -0.883 0.403  
#> 7 SGD     VarX2       -0.0383    0.0104     -3.68  0.00625
```

NOTE: There are
[widely published](https://journalofbigdata.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40537-018-0143-6)
concerns with using stepwise model selection.

Comment: thanks @Till. However, the stepwise regression seems to be running on the full dataset, rather than the individual countries. As shown in the output of `unnest(estimates)`, the terms (Intercept, VarX1, VarX2) have the same values for all countries AUD, EUR and SGD. There is the same issue for `unnest(quality)`, same values

Comment: I updated my answer to process only the data for one country per model. Check out [this tidymodels tutorial](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/statistics/tidy-analysis/), it has some practical examples for this.